# Gathering result using Distributed Data Parallel needs too much video memory

Tags: python, pytorch, concurrency, multi-gpu

the following is my task method used for multi-GPU predicting.

```
def worker(self, rank:int, pickle_file_name:str):
    torch.distributed.init_process_group('nccl', rank=rank, world_size=self.world_size)
    torch.cuda.set_device(device=rank)        
    with torch.no_grad():
        model = self.model_class(gpu_id=rank, **self.model_args).to(rank).eval()
        ddp_model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])
        ddp_model.eval()
        sampler = DistributedSampler(self.dataset, num_replicas=self.world_size, rank=rank)
        dataloader = DataLoader(self.dataset, 
                                batch_size=self.batch_size, 
                                sampler=sampler, 
                                shuffle=False,)
        process_result = []
        all_result = [None] * self.world_size
        for data in dataloader: 
            out:torch.FloatTensor = ddp_model(data)
            out = out.cpu()
            process_result.extend([vec for vec in out])
            if self.batch_end_callback is not None:
                self.batch_end_callback(rank)
    torch.distributed.barrier()
    if rank == 0:
        print()
        print(f'Gather and Save...', end=' ')
    torch.distributed.gather_object(obj=process_result, 
                                    object_gather_list=all_result if rank == 0 else None, 
                                    dst=0)
    if rank == 0:
        pickle.dump(all_result, open(pickle_file_name, mode='wb'))
        print(f'{pickle_file_name}')
    torch.distributed.barrier()
    torch.distributed.destroy_process_group()
```

This code is mostly OK.

But a `torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError` error arises at line `torch.distributed.gather_object()`. It says 12 GB video memory allocation fails.

I don't know why does this happen.

1. I have the line `out = out.cpu()`. All output data to be gathered should have been in system memory, not video memory. Why still allocation failure in video memory?
2. All together I have 17467 output vectors, and every vectors is of dimension 768. That should take only 51 MB (4*768*17467 bytes). Why does it need 12 GB to gather the result?
3. What is the right way to do it?